# Why is a gnu make target with % always rebuilt?

Tags: gnu-make

I seem to be using `%` wrongly in Makefiles. This simple makefile shows the problem

Makefile:

```
mylib:  mylib-%.dll

mylib-%.dll:
    touch mylib-13.dll


myotherlib: myotherlib-13.dll

myotherlib-13.dll:
    touch myotherlib-13.dll
```

Output:

```
> make mylib
touch mylib-13.dll
> make mylib
touch mylib-13.dll

> make myotherlib
touch myotherlib-13.dll
> make myotherlib
make: Nothing to be done for `myotherlib'.
```

mylib is always rebuilt (the second `make mylib` call is again executing the `touch` command), while myotherlib is only built once.

Why is this and what do I need to change so that mylib is not always rebuilt, i.e. the second call to `make mylib` also returns `make: Nothing to be done for 'mylib'.`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Explanation

The target of the rule (the left-hand part of the `:`), unless marked under the `.PHONY` special rule, is supposed to be created at the end of the make process and to exist if you reissue the command right after.

Here your rule `myotherlib-13.dll` does correctly create that target because your rule `myotherlib` directly depends on it and it is a basic rule.

However, your rule `mylib-%.dll` is a pattern rule, it will match a target if possible. The trick lies in your rule `mylib` which depends on the `mylib-%.dll` target. You're telling make `mylib` must depend on a file nammed `mylib-%.dll`, so it looks for a matching rule and finds it, but this rule create a file named `mylib-13.dll` instead so the target creation is never done.

## Demo

If you want a demo of what is happening, change your `touch xxx` commands with `touch $@` (the `$@` is an automatic variable replaced with the name of the rule after replacing the pattern-matching part).

So with

```
mylib: mylib-%.dll

mylib-%.dll:
    touch $@

myotherlib: myotherlib-13.dll

myotherlib-13.dll:
    touch $@
```

And doing

```
$ make mylib
```

You will get the output

```
touch mylib-%.dll
```

## Solution

Simply change `mylib:  mylib-%.dll` to `mylib:  mylib-13.dll` and it will work as intended.

Use the code in the demo and you will see that the `$@` will now correctly be replaced with `mylib13.dll`.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. The reason why I tried using the % is that I did not want the Makefile to be dependent on a version number, so that I don't need to change it when increasing the version e.g. to mylib-14.dll. I wonder if there is some other way to do it. Interesting that makes expects a file named mylib-%.dll to be created when the rule is a pattern rule...

Comment: He expects that because you put it in the requirements part of the rule. If you want to use something more flexible you can use a version variable, i.e. `mylib-$(LATEST_DLL_VERSION).dll` and declare it above the rules to have a single access point.
But at some point you can't expect the system to magically know when you want to bump the version numbers, you have to tell it somewhere.

Comment: That's what I also did, but I hoped there would be a nicer solution where I don't have to put a version number at all. My scenario is: My application depends on a third party library. In the makefile I want to build the library if it's not there, but I don't really care about the version number that I'm using... but that's another question that does not fit into the comments here...

Comment: But how can make know what the version is?  The file containing the version doesn't exist (because this makefile is expected to create it, in your `mylib-%.dll:` pattern rule).  When you first run make there is no file `mylib-13.dll` so how can make know that the version should be "13", and not "betelgeuse"?